# If $0 \rightarrow M' \rightarrow M \xrightarrow[]{f} M'' \rightarrow 0$ is exact then $M$ is Noetherian iff $M',M''$ are.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

> If $0 \rightarrow M' \rightarrow M \xrightarrow[]{f} M'' \rightarrow 0$ is exact then $M$ is Noetherian iff $M',M''$ are.

For an infinite chain $M_i$ in $M$ we have chains $M'_i = M_i \cap M'$ and $ M''_i = f(M_i)$ in $M',M''$, respectively.

If both $M', M''$ are Noetherian then eventually both induced chains will halt; then w.l.o.g. $M'_i, M''_i$ are constant. If $x_i \in M_i \setminus M_{i-1}$ intersects $M'$ then $M'_i \supsetneq M'_{i-1}$, a contradiction...

That's as far as I've gotten. It's not explained in detail in *Atiyah-MacDonald*.

Comment: You can also use the fact that a module is noetherian iff all its submodules are finitely generated. Let $N$ be a submodule of $M$. Then $N\cap M'$ and $f(N)$ are finitely generated and there is a short exact sequence $0\to N\cap M'\to N\to f(N)\to0$.

Comment: Have you proven the other direction - that if $M$ is noetherian than so are $M'$ and $M''$? Those are both relatively easy, but you've stated the full problem...

Comment: It's certainly easier to prove it with other characterizations of Noetherian, but some of those require axiom of choice to be equivalent, so you might prefer to use the original definition.

Comment: Worrying about whether the axiom of choice is used or not at a point in life when one cannot prove that an extension of noetherian modules is noetherian is rather silly...

Comment: To each his own. When I was at MIT, the professor teaching the class on commutative algebra often made the point to try to show stuff was and wasn't dependent on AoC. Maybe your schooling varied. Publicly characterizing others as silly, however, reflects on you and your character. @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: I have no idea if you are silly or not. What is silly is worrying about whether the axiom of choice is used or not when you are struggling to do basic algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case when $M$ is noetherian is very easy. Any ascending chain in $M'$ is also an ascending chain in $M$, so it stabilizes; for an ascending chain in $M''$, consider the ascending chain in $M$ consisting of the inverse images.

The converse implication is a bit harder. Let $L_0\subseteq L_1\subseteq\dots\subseteq L_n\subseteq \dotsb$ be an ascending chain in $M$.

Then, by assumption, the chain $L_0\cap M'\subseteq L_1\cap M'\subseteq\dots\subseteq L_n\cap M'\subseteq \dotsb$ stabilizes. Say that
$$
L_n\cap M'=L_k\cap M'\text{, for all $n\ge k$}
$$
On the other hand, the chain $f(L_0)\subseteq f(L_1)\subseteq\dots\subseteq f(L_n)\subseteq \dotsb$ stabilizes as well, so we can say that
$$
f(L_n)=f(L_k)\text{, for all $n\ge k$}
$$
(as it's not restrictive to use the same $k$ for both chains, just take the largest index from which both chains are stable).

Our task is now to show that $L_n=L_k$, for all $n\ge k$. Take $x\in L_n$; then $f(x)\in f(L_n)=f(L_k)$, so we can write $f(x)=f(y)$, for some $y\in L_k$. Now $x-y\in M'$, so $x-y\in L_n\cap M'$ and therefore $x-y\in L_k\cap M'$. Thus
$$
x=(x-y)+y\in L_k
$$

Comment: Could someone explain why $x-y\in M'$?

Comment: @Brofessor $f(x-y)=f(x)-f(y)=0$, so $x-y\in\ker f=M’$

Comment: sorry why is $\text{ker}f$ equal to $M'$? thanks again

Comment: @Brofessor $0\to M’\to M\xrightarrow{f}M’’\to0$ is exact by assumption.

Comment: @egreg if the sequence is exact then we get $\hbox{Ker} f=\hbox{Im} (M'\longrightarrow M)$ which is subset $M$ so please can you explain why $\hbox{Ker} f=M'$.

Comment: @Santa-claus It's not restrictive to assume that $M'$ is a submodule of $M$ (which is actually what the OP does).

Comment: @egreg I still not understand why they are equal, please provide a detail if you can.

Comment: @Santa-claus Not only it is a submodule, but the map $M'\to M$ is the inclusion. So $\ker f=M'$ by the very definition of exact sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two books that have explained the theorem more:

- *Hungerford*'s book *Algebra* "page.373 Theorem 1.5".
- *Steps in Commutative Algebra* by *Sharp* ["Proposition. 7.17"](https://books.google.com/books?id=Oi4x9NznFEUC&q=M+is+Noetherian+if+and+only+if+both+G+and+M%2FG+are#v=snippet&q=M%20is%20Noetherian%20if%20and%20only%20if%20both%20G%20and%20M%2FG%20are&f=false) and "Corollary 7.19"